# How to serve same content with two different host names?

Tags: httpd.conf

I have a website (e.g. www.abc.com) and I have another domain name (e.g. dotobe.xyz.com) which points to the same IP as www.abc.com. 
dotobe.xyz.com is actually a DNS alias of www.abc.com.

Now, if user visits dotobe.xyz.com, user will be redirected to www.abc.com which is reasonable.
However, what I need is to keep the URL unchanged. In other words, I want to serve the same content of my site through both host names (dotobe.xyz.com and www.abc.com) without redirection.

Can Name-Based Virtual host achieve this goal and how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For virtual hosts on apache just point the document root for the two domains to the same directory.

Comment: but what if I defined an IP-based Virtual host and a Name-based Virtual host (points to same IP address) in httpd.conf, which will take precedence if user visits the site through host name?

Comment: Have you tried simply defining a [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#serveralias) …?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, it would be better served on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Name Based virtual hosting should solve this.

In you virtual host file, you will have to dotobe.xyz.com as a ServerAlias.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName www.abc.com
    ServerAlias dotobe.xyz.com
    # Any additional code here
</VirtualHost>
```

Good Luck!